# How to find specific character to create array from string using php

Tags: php, arrays, php-7.2

I have some string like below:

```
'STRIPLED 9.6W 24V 2.7K 120LED IP20 1CM',
'STRIPLED 9.6W 24V 3K 120LED IP20 1CM',
'STRIPLED H 6 W 24V 4K 140 LED IP20 1CM',
'STRIPLED HO 12.3 W 24V 3K 128 LED IP65 1CM',
'STRIPLED HO 20W 24V 2.7K 280 LED IP65 1CM',
'STRIPLED 14.4W 24V 2.7K 180 LED IP65 1 CM',
```

I tried to find some character and to create array like

Expected Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [power] => 9.6W 24V
            [temp] => 2.7
            [degrees] => IP20
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [power] => 9.6W 24V
            [temp] => 3
            [degrees] => IP20
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [power] => HO 12.3 W 24V
            [temp] => 3
            [degrees] => IP65
        )
)
```

but I cannot arrive right solution.

> Explain: STRIPLED **9.6W 24V** **2.7K** 120LED **IP20** 1CM

Here, W & V means power, K means Temp, IP means Degree

---

My tried Code:

```
<?php 
$descriptions = [
    'STRIPLED 9.6W 24V 2.7K 120LED IP20 1CM',
    'STRIPLED 9.6W 24V 3K 120LED IP20 1CM',
    'STRIPLED H 6 W 24V 4K 140 LED IP20 1CM',
    'STRIPLED HO 12.3 W 24V 3K 128 LED IP65 1CM',
    'STRIPLED HO 20W 24V 2.7K 280 LED IP65 1CM',
    'STRIPLED 14.4W 24V 2.7K 180 LED IP65 1 CM',
]; 

$desc = [];
foreach($descriptions as $key=>$val){
    $desc[$key]['power'] = strstr($val, 'V', true);
    $desc[$key]['temp'] = strstr($val, 'K', true);
    $desc[$key]['degrees'] = strstr($val, 'IP', true);
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($desc).exit;
?>
```

I am seeing output like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [power] => STRIPLED 9,6W 24
            [temp] => STRIPLED 9,6W 24V 2,7
            [degrees] => STR
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [power] => STRIPLED 9,6W 24
            [temp] => STRIPLED 9,6W 24V 3
            [degrees] => STR
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [power] => STRIPLED H 6 W 24
            [temp] => STRIPLED H 6 W 24V 4
            [degrees] => STR
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [power] => STRIPLED HO 12,3 W 24
            [temp] => STRIPLED HO 12,3 W 24V 3
            [degrees] => STR
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [power] => STRIPLED HO 20W 24
            [temp] => STRIPLED HO 20W 24V 2,7
            [degrees] => STR
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [power] => STRIPLED 14,4W 24
            [temp] => STRIPLED 14,4W 24V 2,7
            [degrees] => STR
        )

)
```

Can anybody give me a solution to create my expected result.

Thanks

Comment: you could simply do `$desc[$key]['power'] = str_replace(',', '.', strstr($val, 'V', true));` this should do the trick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think using [`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) is probably the easiest way to extract the data you want. Based on your sample data, this regex should work:

```
^\w+\s+([^V]+V)\s+([\d.,]+)K.*?(IP\d+)
```

This looks for a word, followed by some number of non `V` characters (the "power" component), then a number before a `K` (the "temperature" component), and finally a string matching `IP` followed by some number of digits (the "degree" component). You could use this code (using [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)) to process the array):

```
$descriptions = [
    'STRIPLED 9.6W 24V 2.7K 120LED IP20 1CM',
    'STRIPLED 9.6W 24V 3K 120LED IP20 1CM',
    'STRIPLED H 6 W 24V 4K 140 LED IP20 1CM',
    'STRIPLED HO 12.3 W 24V 3K 128 LED IP65 1CM',
    'STRIPLED HO 20W 24V 2.7K 280 LED IP65 1CM',
    'STRIPLED 14.4W 24V 2.7K 180 LED IP65 1 CM',
]; 
$desc = array_map(function ($v) { 
            preg_match('/^\w+\s+([^V]+V)\s+([\d.,]+)K.*?(IP\d+)/', $v, $m);
            array_shift($m); 
            return $m; }, $descriptions);
print_r($desc);
```

Output for your sample data:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 9.6W 24V
            [1] => 2.7
            [2] => IP20
        )    
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 9.6W 24V
            [1] => 3
            [2] => IP20
        )    
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => H 6 W 24V
            [1] => 4
            [2] => IP20
        )    
    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => HO 12.3 W 24V
            [1] => 3
            [2] => IP65
        )    
    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => HO 20W 24V
            [1] => 2.7
            [2] => IP65
        )    
    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => 14.4W 24V
            [1] => 2.7
            [2] => IP65
        )    
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/IPjY8)

Comment: Excellent Answer

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this:

```
<?php
$arrays = [
    'STRIPLED 9.6W 24V 2.7K 120LED IP20 1CM',
    'STRIPLED 9.6W 24V 3K 120LED IP20 1CM',
    'STRIPLED H 6 W 24V 4K 140 LED IP20 1CM',
    'STRIPLED HO 12.3 W 24V 3K 128 LED IP65 1CM',
    'STRIPLED HO 20W 24V 2.7K 280 LED IP65 1CM',
    'STRIPLED 14.4W 24V 2.7K 180 LED IP65 1 CM'
];

foreach ($arrays as $array){
    //remove STRIPLED
    $result = [];
    $removedStripled = str_replace('STRIPLED ', "", $array);
    $arr = strtok($removedStripled, 'V');
    $result['power'] = $arr.'V';
    $temp = str_replace($arr.'V', "", $removedStripled);
    $arr = strtok($temp, 'K');
    $result['temp'] = $arr;
    preg_match("/IP.*[0-9\s]/", $removedStripled, $match);
    $degrees = explode(' ', $match[0]);
    $result['degress'] = $degrees[0];

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($result);
    echo "</pre>";
}
```